# Install signed driver on WIndows 7

Tags: windows, driver, signing

I have a signed and cross-signed driver:

```
C:\ElectricEye\drv_win7_amd64\amd64>SignTool verify /v /kp hlwd.sys

Verifying: hlwd.sys
Hash of file (sha1): B1123F97399CE42715D131EEAF385548D872BA4D

Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: StartCom Certification Authority
    Issued by: StartCom Certification Authority
    Expires:   Wed Sep 17 23:46:36 2036
    SHA1 hash: 3E2BF7F2031B96F38CE6C4D8A85D3E2D58476A0F

        Issued to: StartCom Class 3 Primary Intermediate Object CA
        Issued by: StartCom Certification Authority
        Expires:   Wed Oct 25 02:03:55 2017
        SHA1 hash: 660746026115B8DF862C4F5CF1C51508E96E33D0

            Issued to: Onmoon Company LLC -  " "
            Issued by: StartCom Class 3 Primary Intermediate Object CA
            Expires:   Sat Oct 22 03:51:20 2016
            SHA1 hash: 875C77748516F09C663C2F4F0CF9C60C68910017

The signature is timestamped: Wed Oct 23 16:37:03 2013
Timestamp Verified by:
    Issued to: StartCom Certification Authority
    Issued by: StartCom Certification Authority
    Expires:   Wed Sep 17 23:46:36 2036
    SHA1 hash: 3E2BF7F2031B96F38CE6C4D8A85D3E2D58476A0F

        Issued to: StartCom Time-Stamping Authority
        Issued by: StartCom Certification Authority
        Expires:   Mon Feb 01 03:59:59 2021
        SHA1 hash: 962FDDD76C6145ADAFA5E9AD98E3020D0821DD81

Cross Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 17:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

        Issued to: StartCom Certification Authority
        Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
        Expires:   Fri Apr 16 00:23:19 2021
        SHA1 hash: E6069E048DEA8D817AFC4188B1BEF1D888D0AF17

            Issued to: StartCom Class 3 Primary Intermediate Object CA
            Issued by: StartCom Certification Authority
            Expires:   Wed Oct 25 02:03:55 2017
            SHA1 hash: 660746026115B8DF862C4F5CF1C51508E96E33D0

                Issued to: Onmoon Company LLC -  " "
                Issued by: StartCom Class 3 Primary Intermediate Object CA
                Expires:   Sat Oct 22 03:51:20 2016
                SHA1 hash: 875C77748516F09C663C2F4F0CF9C60C68910017

Successfully verified: hlwd.sys

Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

I'm trying to install it with

```
sc create hlwd binPath= C:\ElectricEye\drv_win7_amd64\amd64\hlwd.sys type= kernel
```

The installation finishes successfully, but the driver does not load and after a few seconds an error message appears with "Unsigned driver" error.

Audit reports invalid file hash.

Does this mean some kind of signing failue or just Windows 7 drivers can not be installed with `sc`?